# VBA to click Internet Explorer with ONLY Onlick

Tags: html, vba, ms-access, web-scraping, onclick

Because don't work?
Please Help me! :(

[HTML CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcFsS.jpg)

```
Dim i As Long 

Dim IE As Object

Dim Doc As Object

Dim objElement As Object

Dim objCollection As Object

Dim buttonCollection As Object

Dim valeur_heure As Object


' Create InternetExplorer Object

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

' You can uncoment Next line To see form results

IE.Visible = True

' Send the form data To URL As POST binary request

IE.Navigate "http://Mysite/Home/"

Dim elements As Object, element As Object

For Each element In IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("img")

    If element.innertext = "r/std/icons/combi64.png" Then
         element.Focus
        element.Click
        Exit For
    End If

Next

  Set IE = Nothing
```

Comment: 1) Format and edit your code properly please 2) Insert HTML as snippet not as image (use tools provided) 3) Make your question nice and clear 4) Describe what _doesn't work_ means. Error messages? What are they? Which lines? What did you try?

Comment: You also aren't sending _POST binary request_ as far as I can see. And I can't see r/std/icons/combi64.png in the image provided.

Comment: As newbie take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Answer (score 2):

I meant simply

```
IE.Navigate "http://Mysite/Home/"
While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("tbi")(1).Click
```

It is a single element. No For Loop required. No innerText check. Just as shown above. Note that you also need to wait for the page to load; to that end I have added `While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend`.

---

To click on the icon then

```
IE.Document.querySelector("img[src='r/std/icons/combi64.png']").Click
```

But I am not sure the icon is clickable.

Comment: i using your code but don't work. Look a picture error. I use also a break-point for wait page load.

Comment: Try the above E.Document.getElementsByClassName("tbi")(1).Click . And please learn how to edit info into your question using the edit keyword under your question.  Failing all that just  IE.Document.querySelector("img[src='r/std/icons/combi64.png']").Click

Comment: WORK!!! Using only IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("tbi")(1).Click thanks thanks thanks thanks :)